# Close Facebook login window after user logs in

Tags: php, facebook

Hi I am writing a code where - when user clicks on a link, Facebook login opens up in a new window.

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/login/" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/login/', 'newwindow', 'width=700, height=500');return false;"><img src="facebook.png" alt="Facebook Login" style="width:200px;"  /></a>
```

What I want is, If user successfully logs in their facebook profile, the window automatically closes and return to my site's page.

How can I achieve this. Please help.

Comment: you need to use the js sdk: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: Why would you want to have the user login to Facebook? If you want to use Facebook Login _for your website app_, then this is not the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it that way. You need to use FB SDK to redirect. For more information please check below links

1. [Facebook Info](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/)
2. [Facebook Developer](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web)
3. [Online Tutorial](http://www.krizna.com/demo/login-with-facebook-using-php/)

Comment: you should not use shorturls on stackoverflow, i replaced them with the real links instead.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @luschn